# Cohomology and higher structures

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, cohomology, lie-algebra-cohomology, higher-algebra

Classically, cohomologies of Lie groups/algebras parametrize extensions. To be precise, given an linear $G$-action on $M$, there is an bijection between $H^2(G;M)$ and the set of extension $E$ of $G$ by $M$

$$ 1\to M\to E\to G\to 1.$$

Apparently, higher cohomologies correspond to longer extensions such as

$$ 1\to M\to F\to E\to G\to 1.$$

Similar statements hold for Lie algebras.

In [Higher-Dimensional Algebra VI: Lie 2-Algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307263), J. Baez et al showed another meaning of higher cohomologies. Given a Lie algebra $\frak{g}$, a linear representation $V$, and a 3-cohomology class $\alpha \in H^3(\frak{g}$$, M)$ we can construct a Lie 2-algebra. In fact, they showed that **all Lie 2-algebras arise this way**!

A naive but natural question is whether this story extends to higher cases. Namely, do $(n+1)$-th cohomology classifies Lie n-algebras, if any? If so, how does do we connect this back to the classical extension theory?

Comment: As far as I know, this is an open position problem.. it is unlikely that you would get an answer here..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I expected as well.. but any pointers to related discussions would help. By the way there's some very informal discussion that addresses a Lie n-algebra as a L-$_\infty$ algebra that concentrates on the lowest n terms.

Comment: I do not know much about that.. I would be more than happy to know more about "Lie $n$-algebra as $L_{\infty}$-algebra that concentrates on the lowest $n$ terms". Do you want to share where you have seen this informal discussion?

Comment: It's somewhere in the n-category cafe.. I couldn't find at this moment..

Comment: Just found a contradictory conclusion in Baez's Lectures on n-Categories and Cohomology, section 4.4: higher cohomologies do give higher groups, but don't classify all of them. To quote, "Group cohomology, as customarily taught, is about
classifying these **‘fairly wimpy’** Postnikov towers .."

Comment: So, what are you expecting after seeing that contradictory conclusion?

Comment: Well, I should mention that it was also in the Q&A part, and the reason given is not complete. So I'd like to see it more clearly, and also see if this applies/fails for other structures.